# How to merge rows conditionally in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I tried reading a table from a pdf file and transformed it into a dataframe but it is considering next line in a cell as a separate row, like this

[image: dataframe=df]

As you can see in above image it is considering every new line as a row,I want to merge every row until there is a value present in first column. such that my dataframe would look like. this

[image]

Is there any way we can achieve this.

Here is the sample data

```
structure(list(V1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA), V2 = c("Chawla Associates", 
"Architects, Interior", "Designers", "J Square", "Designers &", 
"Engineering"), V3 = c("B-102, Sanik Nagar,", "Uttam Nagar, New", 
"Delhi-110059", "H-office: H No.1031,", "Sec-67, Mohali (PB)", 
"431-432, Sec-8,"), V4 = c("253336493", "M-", "9.51242E+11", 
"M-9872815438", "M-98722-22676", NA), V5 = c("-", NA, NA, "Telefax-", 
"0172-", "2574602"), V6 = c("Abhi2874@yahoo.co.in", NA, NA, "vincaljaidka@hotmail.co", 
"m", NA), V7 = c("CA/99/24551", NA, NA, "CA/96/20742", NA, NA
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks

Domnick

Comment: Do not post data as images, use `dput(data)` or, if it is a large data.frame, `dput(head(data, 20))`. Post the output of those commands **in the question**.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Edited the post with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it'd be better to fix this when reading in the file, but if there's no other way, here's a hacky function that will clean-up this particular dataframe.

```
combineRows <- function(df){ 
  newDf <- NULL
  row <- NULL

  for (r in c(1:nrow(df))){
    if(!is.na(df[r,"V1"])){
      if (!is.null(row)){
        if (is.null(newDf)){
          newDf <- row
        } else{
          newDf <- rbind(newDf,row)
        }
      }
      row <- df[r,]
    } else {
      rows <- rbind(row,df[r,])
      row <- apply(rows,2,function(x)paste(ifelse(is.na(x),'',x),collapse=" "))
    }
  }
  newDf <- rbind(newDf,row)

  #cleanup
  newDf <- apply(newDf, 2,trimws)
  rownames(newDf) <- 1:nrow(newDf)
  return(newDf)
}

newDf <- combineRows(df)

> newDf
  V1  V2                                                 V3                                                        
1 "1" "Chawla Associates Architects, Interior Designers" "B-102, Sanik Nagar, Uttam Nagar, New Delhi-110059"       
2 "2" "J Square Designers & Engineering"                 "H-office: H No.1031, Sec-67, Mohali (PB) 431-432, Sec-8,"
  V4                           V5                       V6                          V7           
1 "253336493 M- 9.51242E+11"   "-"                      "Abhi2874@yahoo.co.in"      "CA/99/24551"
2 "M-9872815438 M-98722-22676" "Telefax- 0172- 2574602" "vincaljaidka@hotmail.co m" "CA/96/20742"
```